# Number of Vehicles in Real-Time

Tags: optaplanner

I'm using Optaplanner VRP tool to solve some VRP instances. Is there a way to view the number of vehicles being used in real-time? Also, what algorithm does Optaplanner employ for solving VRP?

Thanks,
Mayank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're listening to new best solution events in real time (`Solver.addSolverListener`), it's straightforward to determine the number of vehicles used, by iterating all `Vehicle` instances and checking if `nextVisit` isn't `null`.

Note that if you want to minimize the number of vehicle used, you'll need to add a hard or softt constraint for that, which is simple: `when Vehicle(nextVisit != null) then addHard(-1); end`

As for the algorithm used to solve VRP: check the solver config XML. We support many algo's, in the vrp benchmark config XML we let them battle against each other to determine the best algo for production.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Geoff.
I was just wondering if the algorithm also supports heterogeneous capacities for vehicles, i.e., Vehicle 1 has capacity 200 and Vehicle 2 has capacity 100... and so on.

Thanks again!!

Comment: I'm very new to Optaplanner. I just ran the runExampls.bat to try out few instances of VRP. Following your suggestion, I made changes to the file "vehicleRoutingScoreRules.drl" located at "optaplanner-distribution-6.3.0.Final\examples\sources\src\main\resources\org\optaplanner\examples\vehiclerouting\solver". Is that even correct? I added the constraint:

rule "minVehicles"
 when
  $vehicle : Vehicle(nextVisit != null)
 then
  scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end

However, I do not see any effects while using the runExamples.bat file. Is there any link I can refer to? Thanks

Comment: see docs "run examples from source" (the .bat and .sh run them from the jar binaries)

Comment: Thanks, Geoff. I was able to run examples from the source. I made the following edit to the vehicleRoutingScoreRules.drl file:

rule "minVehicles"
when
  $vehicle : Vehicle(nextVisit != null)
 then
  scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end


It threw a run-time error. Is there something I'm missing here? Thanks

Comment: Hi Geoff,

After looking at the code, it appears to me that you probably meant "nextCustomer" and not "nextVisit". I made that change and the program seems to be working fine now.

Just a final question. Every time I make some changes to the .drl file, do I need to do the entire Maven 3 build again? It takes a lot of time to build the projects (as it builds all the projects). Thanks.

Comment: Open the maven 3 project in IntelliJ (or eclipse). Building incrementally should work. When I make a change in a drl file, I just click run in Intellij (no need to build with maven for that) and see the results in the UI or unit tests.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Geoff.